# Linear independence of $\{\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x^2}, \frac{1}{x^3}...\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

So trying to show the above and have tried using induction.

If I let P(n) be the statement that "$\{\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x^2}, \frac{1}{x^3}..., \frac{1}{x^n}$} is linearly independent".

It can be shown that firstly, P(1) = $\frac{1}{x}$ is linearly independent because it is not the $0$ "vector".

Next, I want to assume that P(k) is true, i.e.

supposing that $\frac{a_1}{x} + \frac{a_2}{x^2} + \frac{a_3}{x^3}... \frac{a_k}{x^k} = 0 \implies a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = ... = a_k = 0$.

Then suppose we have $\frac{a_1}{x} + \frac{a_2}{x^2} + ... + \frac{a_k}{x^k} + \frac{a_{k+1}}{x^{k+1}}$ and suppose it is 0, then I tried multiplying both sides by $x$ to get:

$a_1 + \frac{a_2}{x} + ... + \frac{a_k}{x^{k-1}} + \frac{a_{k+1}}{x^k} = 0$, but we know that the standard basis for polynomials is a linearly independent set. So $a_{k+1}$ is 0. Then this works for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by induction. So it'll extend naturally into the basis with infinite cardinality.

Is this how it is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One small error... The expression $$a_{1}+\frac{a_{2}}{x}+\frac{a_{3}}{x^{2}}+\frac{a_{4}}{x^{3}}+...+\frac{a_{k+1}}{x^{k}}$$ is not a polynomial.  It is a rational function.

However, we can fix this error in your proof.  Instead of doing the multiplication by $x$, which yielded this non-polynomial, multiply by $x^{k+1}$.  Since it is the largest power of $x$ in the expression, you will obtain a polynomial this time: $$a_{1}x^{k}+a_{2}x^{k-1}+...+a_{k-1}x+a_{k}=0$$  Now you may use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, which tells you that your polynomial here has only finitely many roots, so since we have the zero equation above, it must be that the coefficients are all $0$.  This finishes the proof.

Comment: It is a polynomial in $1/x$, it is not uncommon to say "polynomial in P(x)" where P is some function of x. For instance trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: @mathreadler That is true.  But did TimidMaths know that?  He/she did not make it explicit in his/her proof what was meant by 'polynomial', so I went with what I thought he/she meant.

Comment: I don't know what he knows. But it is an important concept to learn so I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Well, thanks to you, @mathreadler, now he knows.

Comment: Thanks, you two! Also another side question, I want to know if $V = \text{span}{f_1, f_2, ... }$ if V is the vector space of all functions from $(50, \infty)$. I would say no? I can intuitively think of any constant, but lacking rigor to show why..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A polynomial with an infinite number of zeros is zero

Comment: This hint is false if we allow polynomials with infinitely many terms.

Comment: Polynomials can't have infinitely many terms, that would be a power series.

Comment: @vadim123, polynomials are by definition having only finitely many terms.  If it had infinitely many terms, it would be called a power series.  That is an entirely different problem, and issues of interval convergence come into play when considering linear combinations of such series.